# The constant entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose that $f(z)=f(z+1)$ and $|f(z)|\leq e^{|z|}$ for all $z$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

I tried to use Cauchy estimate to show that the first derivative is zero. But it did not work as $R$ goes to infinity $|f'(z)|$ goes to infinity because of $e^{R}$ in the nominator. I have no idea about using the fact that $f(z)=f(z+1)$. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entire function constant, where $f(z)=f(z+1)$ and $|f(z)|< e^{|z|}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221926/entire-function-constant-where-fz-fz1-and-fz-ez)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603506/entire-periodic-function-with-bounded-growth-is-constant?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Start:** You can use Liouville's theorem to show that $$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{\sin(\pi z)}=c.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{\sin(2\pi z)}$ , as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/222335/42969 ?

Comment: @MartinR No, in fact the $2\pi$ in that linked answer is wrong. The function $\sin(\pi z)$ has zero set exactly $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I see, you are right. (But the question is a still a duplicate.)